# Spring Bean Injection in Liferay Scheduled Job

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, liferay

I have a scheduled job running in liferay 6.1.2 which requires spring injection.

Sample code -

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.Message; 
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListener; 
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException;    
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;


public class ScheduledJob implements MessageListener {      

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @Override
    public void receive(final Message msg) throws MessageListenerException {    
        try {
            service.someMethod();
        } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {

        } catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {

        }
    }    
}
```

The injected service is not initialized through application context and is always null.

Auowiring works perfectly fine for other classes. Only fails for ScheduledJob.

Anyone knows the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try it my self but you can try to implement ApplicationContextAware interface by your ScheduledJob class and get injected beans as described [here](http://www.codeweblog.com/applicationcontextaware/).

Answer (score 0):

Create one class in another package and in that class autowire your service with the help of the constructor by putting @component annotation on class  and @Autowire annotation on parameterized constructor where you will pass serviceobject in paramater.

In this class write one static method which will use your service.
Put this package name in componentscan tag  in spring xml file.

Now in receive method you have to call that method with class name as method is static.